# ArcPad Form Compatibility with previous versions?

Tags: arcpad, forms

Are forms created in ArcPad Studio 10 compatible with previous editions of ArcPad?

I have lots of units loaded with ArcPad 7 and no way to get custom forms on them (I lack ArcPad Studio or Application Builder 7). I'm trying to get basic things like pull down menus and checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Although, I don't have a way to test it, the code and such is the same.  There may be a few upgrades in certain parts of the code that may not display the same or wrong (Just like anything attempting to be backwards compatible that far off), but I can't foresee a a problem.

You may need to edit the form directly (*.apl file) and maybe even manually transfer the file, but yes it should.